# Detecting where a change event came from

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I have a bunch of JTextComponents that fire update events to a common model.  The model then fires out change events to the other components so they can all be in synch.  How can I detect which one fired the event initially so as not to fire the event back?  I ask this as I'm currently getting an expection due to attemtping to update the component that fired the event.

Answer (score 4):

There should be a [`getSource`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()) method on the event object. Use that to obtain a reference to the component that originally fired the event. You can then skip that component when distributing the event.